# Developing a gem: File write access issues

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm developing a gem and it creates files in a `tmp/` directory. The problem is, when users use my gem. And when the gem tries to store `tmp` files it issues a permission problem. I wonder how I can solve this without the user need to `chown/chmod` the tmp folder or run as `sudo`?

Comment: How do you specify tmp/ location? If you use it directly (e.g. File.open('tmp/xxx'), it depends on where your gem code is invoked from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use the Ruby Tempfile class?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple workaround (for unix systems) - use `/tmp/`

Comment: Dangerous sometimes-- other apps and users may be able to read these files.

Answer (score 0):

How about `ENV['TEMP']`? - Should be universal.